# Oracle Stored Procedure - Spring Integration - OUT Type Object

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-integration

Is it possible to have Oracle type object as an output from a stored procedure, calling same using spring integration?

For example, I have the following in the database:

```
create or replace TYPE ESP_TRAINING_REQ_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(
    v_param1 varchar2(25),
    v_param2 varchar2(25)
);

create or replace TYPE ESP_TRAINING_RESP_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(
    v_param1 varchar2(25),
    v_param2 varchar2(25)
);

create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (
    v_req_obj IN ESP_TRAINING_REQ_OBJ,
    v_resp_obj OUT ESP_TRAINING_RESP_OBJ
) AS
BEGIN
    v_resp_obj := ESP_TRAINING_RESP_OBJ(v_req_obj.v_param2, v_req_obj.v_param1);
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_PROC');
END;
```

However, when I try calling it, I'm getting the following exception:

> PLS-00306:  wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROC'

Please find spring integration configuration bellow:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="ESP_TRAINING" request-channel="inputChannel"
        stored-procedure-name="TEST_PROC" data-source="dataSource"
        reply-channel="outputChannel"
        skip-undeclared-results="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">

        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="v_req_obj" direction="IN" type="STRUCT" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="v_resp_obj" direction="OUT" type="STRUCT" />

        <int-jdbc:parameter name="v_req_obj" expression="payload.v_req_obj"/>

    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Please note it works fine if we change SP declaration above, for using STRUCT in request only, for example replacing ESP_TRAINING_RESP_OBJ by a VARCHAR or any other Oracle primitive data type.

For Example:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (
    v_req_obj IN ESP_TRAINING_REQ_OBJ,
    v_status OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    v_status := v_req_obj.v_param1 || ' and ' || v_req_obj.v_param2;
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_PROC');
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`return-type`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures) on the `<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition>` for `OUT` param and [`SqlReturnStruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#d0e2296) must help you to solve the issue.

The test-case in the Framework source codes contains this sample for `CLOB` handling:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway request-channel="getMessageChannel"
                                       data-source="dataSource"
                                       stored-procedure-name="GET_MESSAGE"
                                       ignore-column-meta-data="true"
                                       expect-single-result="true"
                                       reply-channel="output2Channel">
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="message_id"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="message_json" type="CLOB" direction="OUT" type-name="" return-type="clobSqlReturnType"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="message_id" expression="payload"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

<bean id="clobSqlReturnType" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="spy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.storedproc.ClobSqlReturnType"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it doing following:

1. Updated spring integration version to 3.0.0.RELEASE,
   giving support to both type-name and return-type attribues, inside sql-parameter-definition.
2. Updated stored procedured declaration as follows:

   ```
   <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
       id="ESP_TRAINING" request-channel="inputChannel"
       stored-procedure-name="TEST_PROC" data-source="dataSource"
       reply-channel="outputChannel"
       skip-undeclared-results="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">

           <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="v_req_obj" direction="IN" type="STRUCT" />
           <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="v_resp_obj" direction="OUT" type="STRUCT" type-name="ESP_TRAINING_RESP_OBJ" return-type="espTrainingRespObj" />

           <int-jdbc:parameter name="v_req_obj" expression="payload.v_req_obj"/>

   </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

   <beans:bean id="espTrainingRespObj" class="com.hsbc.esp.EspTrainingRespObj"/>
   ```
3. Changed EspTrainingRespObj to implement SQLReturnType, as follows:

   ```
   public class EspTrainingRespObj implements SqlReturnType {

       private String param1;
       private String param2;

       public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,     int sqlType, String typeName) 
           throws SQLException {
           Object[] attributes = ((STRUCT) cs.getObject(paramIndex)).getAttributes();
           this.param1 = (String) attributes[0];
           this.param2 = (String) attributes[1];
           return this;
       }
   ...
   }
   ```